# How to redirect a user not logged in to a different page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to redirect a user that is not logged in to the page I created to log in. I wrote the code in the functions.php of the theme but it seems like that it doesn't working.

```
<?php 
if (is_page($page = 'private-gallery' )) {
 if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
 template_redirect ('http://www.site.it/wp/private-area' );
 exit;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Put it in your header.php for generic redirections, or in your template file concerning the page. for exemple, if tpl-specific require to be logged in to have the access, then put your code at the start of your template.

Comment: @kevinniel doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by hooking into the `template_redirect` [[action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)]. (note that you can also use an earlier executed hook, but I mostly use this for ease).

This way you can retrieve the current post slug, and based on this do your statement comparison to see if the current page is `private-gallery`.

In the below method the `wp_redirect()` [[function reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)] is used to redirect to the correct page. The `home_url()` [[function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)] is used to retrieve the home URL for the current site (always try to avoid use full path URL's whenever possible).

The wp_redirect basically executes `header("Location: $location", true, $status);` where `$status` is **302** by default .

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'gianni_private_gallery_redirect');
function gianni_private_gallery_redirect(){
    global $post;
    if($post){
        if( $post->post_name=='private-gallery' ) {
            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                // By default a 302 redirect.
                // Add your custom status code as second parameter if required.
                wp_redirect( home_url( '/private-area/' ) ); 
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```